# ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor View: How to add loop control variable to Text and Value attribute of SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

For instance, here's my code:

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "i",
            Value = "i"
        }
        );
    }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Level, listItems, "-- Select --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Level)
```

This is what I want to do. I want to populate the dropdown list with the loop control variables with each iteration, i.e. for i = 1, `Text` and `Value` will be "1"; for i = 2, `Text` and `Value` will be "2" and so on.

How can I achieve this in Razor?

Whenever I try the above code, only "i" is displayed 5 times, but I want 1 through 5 to be displayed.

ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 5

Comment: Its `Text = i.ToString(), Value=i.ToString()` (no quotes), but this can be simplified to `var listItems = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 5));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I tried Text = i.ToString() and Value = i.ToString() and it worked for me. I'll try out the second one and then let you know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = i.ToString(),
        Value = i.ToString()
    });
}
```

However this can be simplified to a single line

```
SelectList listItems = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 5));
```

But in anycase, this code belongs in the controller, not the view (and assign it to (preferably) a view model property or a `ViewBag` property.